# How to write(save) files to a directory instead of desktop?

Tags: python, directory

Here is my code:

```
f = open("myfile.txt")
f.write("Writing something")
f.close()

plt.savefig('plot1.png')
plt.savefig('plot2.png')


workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('results.xlsx')
workbook.close()
```

At the moment, these files are being saved to my desktop. How would i save them to a file that the user specifies the name for? So i would have a widget like so:

```
    self.directoryname= tkinter.Entry(self.master)
    self.directoryname["width"] = 60
    self.directoryname.focus_set()
    self.directoryname.grid(row=1, column=1)

    foldername = (self.directoryname.get())
```

How can i take foldername and create a directory with that name, and store the files in there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `os.path.join()` function and  if you want to create a folder `os.makedirs()`

```
import os
path = "some/path/to/location"
foldername = (self.directoryname.get())
file_path = os.path.join(path,foldername)
os.makedirs(file_path)
filename = 'results.xlsx'
full_path = os.path.join(file_path,filename)
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(full_path)
workbook.close()
```